# How to make a draggable div resize-able on all 4 corners with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I noticed these resize pointers in the css spec...

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#valdef-cursor-se-resize

Is there a CSS shortcut for 4 corner resizability similar to the one corner ('resize: both') method?
If not, are there known conflicts when combining resizability with a draggable div?

My starting point was here...

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp

Any help navigating the posX, posY is appreciated.

notes for getBoundingClient()
———---
|     |
|____ |     div.getBoundingClientRect()

SE (bottom right):
Height and width     /   top and left are stationary

SW (bottom left):
Height and width and left  /   top is stationary

NW (top left):
Height and width top and left

NE (top right):
Height and width and Top    /   Left is stationary

edit: removed padding and borders.

```js
const myDiv = document.getElementById('mydiv')
let isResizing = false;
//Make the DIV element draggable:
dragElement(myDiv);
   

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  if (!isResizing) {
  let pos1 = 0,
    pos2 = 0,
    pos3 = 0,
    pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    //if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    //otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
      pos3 = e.clientX;
      pos4 = e.clientY;
      document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
      // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
      document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }
  

  function elementDrag(e) {
    
      e = e || window.event;
      e.preventDefault();
      // calculate the new cursor position:
      pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
      pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
      pos3 = e.clientX;
      pos4 = e.clientY;
      // set the element's new position:
      elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
      elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }
  
  function closeDragElement() {
    //stop moving when mouse button is released:
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
 }
}
// Resize
(function fourCorners() {

const resizers = document.querySelectorAll('.resizer')
let currentResizer

for (let resizer of resizers) {
  resizer.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown)

  function mouseDown(e) {
    currentResizer = e.target
    e.preventDefault()
    isResizing = true;

    let posX = e.clientX;
    let posY = e.clientY;
    myDiv.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove)
    myDiv.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp)

    function mouseMove(e) {
       e.preventDefault()
      const rect = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect()
      if (currentResizer.classList.contains('se')) {
        //console.log(currentResizer.classList.value)

        myDiv.style.width = rect.width - (posX - e.clientX) + 'px';
        myDiv.style.height = rect.height - (posY - e.clientY) + 'px';
      } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains('sw')) {
        //console.log(currentResizer.classList.value)

        myDiv.style.width = rect.width + (posX - e.clientX) + 'px';
        myDiv.style.height = rect.height - (posY - e.clientY) + 'px';
        myDiv.style.left = rect.left - (posX - e.clientX) + 'px';

      } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains('ne')) {
        //console.log(currentResizer.classList.value)

        myDiv.style.width = rect.width - (posX - e.clientX) + 'px';
        myDiv.style.height = rect.height + (posY - e.clientY) + 'px';
        myDiv.style.top = rect.top - (posY - e.clientY) + 'px';

      } else {
        //console.log(currentResizer.classList.value)

        myDiv.style.width = rect.width + (posX - e.clientX) + 'px';
        myDiv.style.height = rect.height + (posY - e.clientY) + 'px';
        myDiv.style.top = rect.top - (posY - e.clientY) + 'px';
        myDiv.style.left = rect.left - (posX - e.clientX) + 'px';

      }
      posX = e.clientX;
      posY = e.clientY;
    }

    function mouseUp(e) {
      myDiv.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove)
      myDiv.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp)
      isResizing = false
    }
  }
}
})()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding : 0;
}

#mydiv {
  position: absolute; /* NECESSARY */
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  /* border: 1px solid #222; */ 
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  /* resize: both; /* CSS RESIZE */
  overflow: hidden; /* CSS RESIZE */
}

#mydivheader {
  /* padding: 10px; */
  cursor: move;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: #fff;
}

#content {
  color: #000;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}


/* ::-webkit-resizer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  background-color: #dd0;
  z-index: 2;
} */

.resizer {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: #dd0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.resizer.nw {
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  cursor: nw-resize;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.resizer.ne {
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  cursor: ne-resize;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}

.resizer.sw {
  bottom: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  cursor: sw-resize;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

.resizer.se {
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  cursor: se-resize;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
  <div class='resizer nw'></div>
  <div class='resizer ne'></div>
  <div class='resizer sw'></div>
  <div class='resizer se'></div>

  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move

    <div id='content'>

      <div id='image-container'><img height='auto' width='100%' src='https://picsum.photos/600' /></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I update the question with current progress.

Comment: I see what you mean by the posX, posY problem.  One "improvement" would be to get rid of the scrollbars I can see: You can change in rule `#mydiv` `overflow: auto;` to `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: I like what you're trying to do, but at this moment I am too busy to have a real close look at this. It's rather complex. Maybe I'll have a look later, when I'm less busy and noone else has looked at it.

Comment: It's getting closer but i'm getting strange behavior from the mouseup remove event listeners not triggering and the box continues to resize.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you want to make it nice and easy you could use jQuery to help it resize would probably be the easiest way. Then after you learn how to do it with jQuery you could do it with pure js.

Comment: I'm 4 months into javascript and really enjoying it. I want to have a more solid understanding before moving into libraries. This is an exercise.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry that is what I was doing too when I was new.

Comment: I almost have this working... its not very robust tho. The event listeners dont always remove on mouse up and things get ugly

Comment: You could try to set a loop that checks every millisecond to make sure that the event listener is removed on mouse up.

Answer (score -1):

So, you want the resize handle to appear on all four corners? That'll require some bounds checking.

You can modify the offset check in `drag` to account for any corner and handle the drag as a resize event instead. The code somewhat works for top-left and bottom-right resizing, but doe not work too well with the opposite corners. This is a start.

This is a start:

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('#cursor');
const cornerThreshold = 4;

const dragStart = e => {
  const [ horz, vert ] = getDirection(e, cornerThreshold);
  const bounds = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const cursor = getCursorType(e);
  
  if (cursor === 'grab') {
    e.target.dataset.isDragging = true;
  } else {
    e.target.dataset.isResizing = true;
  }

  e.target.dataset.startWidth = bounds.width;
  e.target.dataset.startHeight = bounds.height;
  e.target.dataset.originX = e.clientX;
  e.target.dataset.originY = e.clientY;
  e.target.dataset.offsetX = e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft;
  e.target.dataset.offsetY = e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop;
  e.target.dataset.dirHorz = horz;
  e.target.dataset.dirVert = vert;
  e.target.style.zIndex = 999;
};

const dragEnd = e => {
  delete e.target.dataset.isDragging;
  delete e.target.dataset.offsetX;
  delete e.target.dataset.offsetY;
  delete e.target.dataset.originX;
  delete e.target.dataset.originY;
  delete e.target.dataset.startWidth;
  delete e.target.dataset.startHeight;
  delete e.target.dataset.dirHorz;
  delete e.target.dataset.dirVert;
  delete e.target.dataset.resizeDirection;
  
  e.target.style.removeProperty('z-index');
  e.target.style.removeProperty('cursor');
};

const drag = e => {
  e.target.style.cursor = getCursorType(e);
  cursor.textContent = `(${e.clientX}, ${e.clientY})`;
  if (e.target.dataset.isDragging) {
    e.target.style.left = `${e.clientX - parseInt(e.target.dataset.offsetX, 10)}px`;
    e.target.style.top = `${e.clientY - parseInt(e.target.dataset.offsetY, 10)}px`;
  } else if (e.target.dataset.isResizing) {
    const bounds = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    const startWidth = parseInt(e.target.dataset.startWidth, 10);
    const startHeight = parseInt(e.target.dataset.startWidth, 10);
    const deltaX = e.clientX - parseInt(e.target.dataset.originX, 10);
    const deltaY = e.clientY - parseInt(e.target.dataset.originY, 10);
    const originX = parseInt(e.target.dataset.originX, 10);
    const originY = parseInt(e.target.dataset.originY, 10);
    const dirHorz = parseInt(e.target.dataset.dirHorz, 10);
    const dirVert = parseInt(e.target.dataset.dirVert, 10);
    
    if (dirHorz < 0) {
      e.target.style.left = `${originX + deltaX}px`;
      e.target.style.width = `${startWidth - deltaX}px`
    } else if (dirHorz > 0) {
      e.target.style.width = `${startWidth + deltaX}px`;
    }
    if (dirVert < 0) {
      e.target.style.top = `${originY + deltaY}px`;
      e.target.style.height = `${startHeight - deltaY}px`;
    } else if (dirVert > 0) {
      e.target.style.height = `${startHeight + deltaY}px`;
    }
  }
};

const focus = e => { };

const unfocus = e => { e.target.style.removeProperty('cursor'); };

const getDirection = (e, threshold) => {
  const bounds = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const offsetX = e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft;
  const offsetY = e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop;

  const isTop = offsetY <= threshold;
  const isLeft = offsetX <= threshold;
  const isBottom = offsetY > (bounds.height - threshold);
  const isRight = offsetX > (bounds.width - threshold);
  
  if      (isTop    && isLeft)  return [ -1, -1 ];
  else if (isTop    && isRight) return [ -1,  1 ];
  else if (isBottom && isLeft)  return [  1, -1 ];
  else if (isBottom && isRight) return [  1,  1 ];
  else                          return [  0,  0 ];
};

const getCursorType = (e) => {
  if (e.target.dataset.isDragging) {
    return 'grabbing';
  } else {
    const [ horz, vert ] = getDirection(e, cornerThreshold);

    const isTop = vert === -1;
    const isLeft = horz === -1;
    const isBottom = vert === 1;
    const isRight = horz === 1;
  
    if ((isTop && isLeft) || (isBottom && isRight)) return 'nwse-resize';
    if ((isTop && isRight) || (isBottom && isLeft)) return 'nesw-resize';
  }
  return 'grab';
};

document.querySelectorAll('.draggable').forEach(draggable => {
 draggable.addEventListener('mousedown', dragStart);
 draggable.addEventListener('mouseup', dragEnd);
 draggable.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
 draggable.addEventListener('mouseenter', focus);
 draggable.addEventListener('mouseleave', unfocus);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  height: 60%;
  border: thin solid grey;
}

.square {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
}

.color-red { background: red; }
.color-blue { background: blue; }
.color-green { background: green; }

#square-1 { top:  10px; left:  10px; }
#square-2 { top:  50px; left:  50px; }
#square-3 { top: 100px; left: 100px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="square-1" class="square color-red draggable resizable"></div>
  <div id="square-2" class="square color-blue draggable resizable"></div>
  <div id="square-3" class="square color-green draggable resizable"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div>Cursor: <span id="cursor">(0, 0)</span></div>
```

Comment: The drag function woks fine on its own and I'm looking at the resize as separate 'plug-in' function. But I like your idea to integrate the two for future attempt. What do you know about e.preventDefault() with regard to resize?

Comment: i found my issue, or one of them, stems from the border and padding attributes being added.. they appear to be multiplying exponentially. (offset)